# Styling a FlowGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I tried to re-style a flow graph found via [`FindMaximumFlow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximumFlow.html), but this seems not to work:

```
vertices = {"s", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "t"};
flows = {40, 30, 10, 22, 30, 54, 50, 37, 17, 32};
edges = {"s" <-> 1, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> "t", "s" <-> 4, 
         4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 3, 2 <-> 6, 6 <-> 4, 6 <-> "t"};
```

then

```
flowGraph = Graph[vertices,
   edges,
   EdgeCapacity -> flows,
   EdgeWeight -> flows,
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
   VertexSize -> Medium,
   GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding",
   EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center], 
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Medium]];
```

Now determining the optimum:

```
ℱ = FindMaximumFlow[flowGraph, "s", "t", "OptimumFlowData"];
```

with

```
g = ℱ["FlowGraph"]
```

So far everything is fine. But styling with something like

```
ℱ["FlowGraph", GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork"]
```

does not work. When doing a right-click in the output (of `F["FlowGraph"]`) the styling options are offered and this works fine, but not when applying directly. At the moment my workaround is extracting the adjacency matrix and process this matrix. But I would prefer to choose directly a style. Has anyone a hint how this could be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
g = ℱ["FlowGraph"];
SetProperty[RemoveProperty[g, DeleteCases[PropertyList[g], GraphLayout]], 
            GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**What is happening:** [GraphStyle >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphStyle.html) says:

> Direct settings of any of *Graph* options override base settings provided by *GraphStyle*.

And, as can be seen using

```
PropertyList[ℱ["FlowGraph"]]
```

> {EdgeShapeFunction, EdgeStyle, EdgeWeight, GraphHighlight, GraphHighlightStyle, GraphLayout, GraphStyle, VertexCoordinates, 
>   VertexShape, VertexShapeFunction, VertexSize, VertexStyle, 
>   VertexWeight}

many of styling options are set in `ℱ["FlowGraph"]`, and they need to be removed for `GraphStyle` to work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I´ve seen the settings in `FullForm` but had not the idea of removing the properties ;-)

Comment: @mgamer, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.