# Highlight a sub graph with special properties

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This question is related to that one:[Styling a flow graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114551/styling-a-flowgraph/114554#114554).
For a demonstration of a flowgraph I "styled" such a graph (an intermediate result in the algorithm of Ford-Fulkerson) in the following way:

```
    display = {Property["s" \[DirectedEdge] 4, EdgeWeight -> "0,30"],
   Property["s" \[DirectedEdge] 1, EdgeWeight -> "10"], 
   Property[
    1 \[DirectedEdge] "s", {EdgeWeight -> "30", EdgeStyle -> Red}], 
   Property[
    2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, {EdgeWeight -> "30", EdgeStyle -> Red}],
   Property[
    3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, {EdgeWeight -> "10", EdgeStyle -> Red}],
   Property[4 \[DirectedEdge] 5, EdgeWeight -> "0,54"],
   Property[5 \[DirectedEdge] 3, EdgeWeight -> "0,50"],
   Property[6 \[DirectedEdge] 4, EdgeWeight -> "0,17"],
   Property[2 \[DirectedEdge] 6, EdgeWeight -> "17"],
   Property[
    6 \[DirectedEdge] 2, {EdgeWeight -> "20", EdgeStyle -> Red}],
   Property[6 \[DirectedEdge] "t", EdgeWeight -> "12"],
   Property[
    "t" \[DirectedEdge] 6, {EdgeWeight -> "20", EdgeStyle -> Red}],
   Property[3 \[DirectedEdge] "t", EdgeWeight -> "12"],
   Property[
    "t" \[DirectedEdge] 3, {EdgeWeight -> "10", EdgeStyle -> Red}]};
```

This yields the following graph:

[image: Intermediate Result]

Next steps to find a path from "s" to "t", via `FindPath` - no problem

```
paths = FindPath[display, "s", "t", \[Infinity], All]
(*{{"s", 4, 5, 3, "t"}, {"s", 4, 5, 3, 2, 6, "t"}}*)
```

But the attempt to highlight one of these paths in the graph of the intermediate result is not successful, only the vertices are highlighted and I (so far) could not manage to get the edges highlighted (eg. dashed, or different color). So this code was (and is) nut successful:

```
Graph[display, EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center],
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", GraphHighlightStyle -> "Dashed"];
```

Has anyone an hint for me how to mange it? Removing the properties as in the cited question would remove "my" properties.

Side question: I used "EdgeWeight" for the capacities, if I use "EdgeCapacity" these numbers are not shown when using `EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeCapacity", Center]`. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps,

Using,

```
g = Graph[display, EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center], 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork"]
```

then,

```
HighlightGraph[g, {Style[#, Green] & /@ paths[[1]], 
  Style[#, Green] & /@ DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[paths[[1]], 2, 1]}]
```

[image]

or to get default highlight styles:

```
HighlightGraph[g, DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[paths[[1]], 2, 1], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Dashed"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. (I still do not understand completely why my approach did not work) I tried e.g. ´HighlightGraph[display, PathGraph[{"s", 4, 5, 3, "t"}], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Dashed"]´ but only got the vertices highlighted.